# Can't implement D3.js to React with useRef. What is the correct way?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart with d3.js and implement it to React as a function component with hooks.

I tried to use `useRef`. Initialized them as null and then set them in the JSX as you can see in the code. When I want to use `clientWidth` which uses `lineChart` ref it says it is null.

I thought of creating an initializeDrawing function which will initialize empty assignments but then since component doesn't refresh at variable changes it doesn't work. I also thought of carrying those variables to `useState` but it doesn't seem like a good solution.

I want to learn from you what is the best solution to implement d3.js charts with function components.

I am trying to implement [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/gordlea/27370d1eea8464b04538e6d8ced39e89), but learning general principles of implementing d3.js to react function components with hooks is the main goal.

Here is the code:

```
...
...
...
const LineChart: FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  let dataArrIndex = 0;
  const lineChart = useRef((null as unknown) as HTMLDivElement);
  const xAxis = useRef((null as unknown) as SVGGElement);
  const yAxis = useRef((null as unknown) as SVGGElement);
  const margin = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 };
  const aspectRatio = 9 / 16;
  const chartWidth = lineChart.current.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  const chartHeight =
    lineChart.current.clientWidth * aspectRatio - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([chartHeight, 0]);
  const xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, chartWidth]);
  const update = () => {
    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(
        data,
        (d): number => {
          return d[dataArrIndex].balance;
        },
      ) as number,
    ]);

    xScale.domain(data[dataArrIndex].map((d) => d.month));

    d3.select(yAxis.current).call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    d3.select(xAxis.current).call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  };
  return (
    <div className="line-chart" ref={lineChart}>
      <svg width={chartWidth} height={chartHeight}>
        <g transform={`translate(${margin.left},${margin.bottom})`} />
        <g ref={yAxis} />
        <g ref={xAxis} />
        <path />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LineChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to use ref for element before this element created in dom, so you have null instead of ref to htmlelement. To solve your issue you need to wrap all code that uses refs to useEffect hook.

Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const chartWidth = lineChart.current.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  const chartHeight =
    lineChart.current.clientWidth * aspectRatio - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([chartHeight, 0]);
  const xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, chartWidth]);
  const update = () => {
    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(
        data,
        (d): number => {
          return d[dataArrIndex].balance;
        },
      ) as number,
    ]);

    xScale.domain(data[dataArrIndex].map((d) => d.month));

    d3.select(yAxis.current).call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    d3.select(xAxis.current).call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  };
}
```

Use effect uses in functional component as the analog for componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate/componentWillUnmount

And if you need to call method 'update' every time when component receive updates you need to move it from useEffect to function body and call it in ueEffect:

```
const update = () => {
    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(
        data,
        (d): number => {
          return d[dataArrIndex].balance;
        },
      ) as number,
    ]);

    xScale.domain(data[dataArrIndex].map((d) => d.month));

    d3.select(yAxis.current).call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    d3.select(xAxis.current).call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  };

useEffect(() => {
  const chartWidth = lineChart.current.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  const chartHeight =
    lineChart.current.clientWidth * aspectRatio - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([chartHeight, 0]);
  const xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, chartWidth]);
  update();
}
```

You can use attributes like width height in several ways:

1. Set it to state using useState hook: const { width, setWidth } = useState(0) and update it in useEffect from ref
2. Check if ref !== null `<svg width={chartRef && chartRef.current.offsetWidth}  />`

Comment: But how can I use, for example, clientWidth in JSX elements' attributes in this setup?

Comment: @MehmetEgemenAlbayrak answer added

Comment: @IgorStetsiura Why is the `useRef` necessary?  Isn't `useEffect` guaranteed to run after the DOM has been updated?